# Read only the first column whose row elements > 0 for every row within a matrix

Tags: r

Original matrix below:

```
3 -1 4
0 2 1
```

Looking to get a vector containing the values: 3, 2. Only the elements in each row which are greater than 0, and only for the first column. Assume all rows contain at least one element > 0. Suggestions?

Comment: What about rows which do not contain any value > 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like there should be something simpler, but here's an option:

```
#With mat as your matrix
apply(mat, 1, function(x) x[x > 0][1]) #@tonytonov's improvement
#[1] 3 2
```

Comment: @tonytonov - I think so